# Xamarin animation causing my application to skip many frames

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a main View Page, with a frame & image (inside drawable folder). on Back-end i am doing simple animation for 3 seconds

**My Question:**

How am I doing too much work by simple animation and image is 500x500. How to fix this error?

By the way, it works fine, if i remove animation code `Task.WhenAll`

```
Thread started:  #5
[Choreographer] Skipped 1191 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 [ViewRootImpl@5028d58[MainActivity]] dispatchAttachedToWindow
[me.idcardwalle] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 1534(155KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 69% free, 2MB/8MB, paused 53us total 16.620ms
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 168 objects 168 opaque 0 colors 168 colors-bridged 168 colors-visible 168 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.05ms tarjan 0.04ms scc-setup 0.05ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.03ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 17.71ms
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 3.13ms, stw 4.30ms promoted 158K major size: 3984K in use: 3218K los size: 4096K in use: 3634K
...
[Choreographer] Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[ViewRootImpl@5028d58[MainActivity]] MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) or=1
[InputMethodManager] prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@a5c60a8[MainActivity]
[InputMethodManager] getNavigationBarColor() -855310
```

Animation code

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        ssImage.Opacity = 50;

        await Task.WhenAll(
            ssImage.FadeTo(1, 3000),
            ssImage.ScaleTo(1.2, 3000)
            );

                 var route = $"{ nameof(NewPage)}";
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
 }
```

UI Code

```
 <Frame VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               Padding="0" Margin="0">
            <Frame.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#0087c8" Offset="0.1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#005783"  Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Frame.Background>

            <Image x:Name="ssImage" Source="ssImage.png"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   WidthRequest="300" />
        </Frame>
```

**Update**: I also tried asysn task but same error

```
    await Task.Run(async () => {
            await ssImage.FadeTo(1, 3000);
            await ssImage.ScaleTo(1.2, 3000);
        });
```

Comment: It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve?  Is there an actual error?  What specifically is slow?  You are running 6s of animation, which seems like a huge amount of time - the default is 0.25s.  Animations are UI operations and must be run on the UI thread.

Comment: i am running only 3 sec animation not 6s. I am trying to fix error (1191 frames skiped). let me know and i can add more details

Comment: That is not an error.  Android generates those kinds of log messages ALL the time.

Comment: just to make sure. are you saying i should ignore this message bc its android generates it all the times? by skipping so many frames, my building menu slide animation freeze and get stuck lil. and its not smooth. if i remove this animation that menu slide animation is smooth. I need lil help with fixing this message so it doesnt skip so many frames. skipping less than 100 frames ok but not 1000-ish. any ideas bc i dont even know what else i can do to debug?

Comment: reason for me fixing this message is bc I also have scrolling issues in my app where some frames are getting skipped. so If i can find out how to fix it, i can fix in my whole app

Comment: *"I also have scrolling issues in my app where some frames are getting skipped"* - scrolling "hiccups" usually have a different cause. If the answer here doesn't help that, then start a new question, with relevant code.

Comment: yes will do and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnAppearing` happens just before the page is diplayed.

To get smooth animation, you want the page to finish displaying before the animation starts. This requires the following two code changes:

1. DO NOT WAIT for the animation to finish - let OnAppearing return.
2. Delay the start of the animation.

Code:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

...
// Start a background thread, so can delay without pausing `OnAppearing`.
// DO NOT have `await`/`async` here.
Task.Run(() => {
    // Give UI thread some time to layout/begin-displaying the page.
    // (Without this, a complex page might still be in layout,
    //  so the animation might start, then hiccup, like the original code.)
    Task.Delay(200);
    // If UI thread is in middle of displaying the page,
    // that is okay; this will run once UI thread is available.
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        // Now we are back on the main thread.
        await ssImage.FadeTo(1, 3000);
        await ssImage.ScaleTo(1.2, 3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that and i makes sense. I added this code inside OnAppearing but the animation (Scale/Fade) doesnt work (its skips though animation). maybe I missed something?

Comment: my mistake... your code works perfect! issue i was going to next page (see upload post). i moved that code inside mainthread now. from 1000-ish skipped frame skip, now only 34 frames skipped. Big difference!! i am guessing 34 skipped frame is somewhat normal?